# Crunch: using -d 1, -d 1% options with first two chars DD

Tags: crunch

I'm trying to generate a list of words where the minimum length is 6 and the max length is 6, where the first pair of characters are fixed and consecutive, the second two characters are upper alpha characters with no consecutive repeats, and the last pair of characters are numbers with no consecutive repeats. Here is the pattern I'm trying to achieve:

|D|D|UpperAlpha|UpperAlpha|Number|Number

Here is what I tried, using the -d option:

`crunch 6 6 -d 1, -d 1% -t DD,,%% -o list.txt`

But it doesn't even generate a single line. To reiterate, the only consecutive repeats are the initial two characters (D|D), while the next two upper-case characters should not repeat, nor should the final two number characters repeat. Can this pattern be achieved with crunch?

I'm using crunch version 3.6.

Comment: According to your requirements, `DDAB01` should be the first word in the list generated by crunch.

Comment: You could just use **`-d 1,%`** instead of `-d 1, -d 1%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Scenario

According to your requirements, the words in your wordlist should have :

1. Two Uppercase D's ie. `DD` followed by
2. Two non-repeating Uppercase characters followd by
3. Two non-repeating Numbers.

Going by the requirements first word should be `DDAB01`. Now , consider these two points :

1. **[man crunch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/crunch.1.html)** and look for **`-t`** option

   ```
   -t @,%^
         Specifies  a pattern, eg: @@god@@@@ where the only the @'s, ,'s,
         %'s, and ^'s will change.
         @ will insert lower case characters
         , will insert upper case characters
         % will insert numbers
         ^ will insert symbols
   ```

   So, any pattern specified by `-t` option is treated as a literal character except for the characters **`@`** , **`,`** , **`%`** and **`^`** that are replaced with characters as defined by crunch.

   In your case pattern is `DD,,%%` that contains `2 repeating literal uppercase D's`
2. Now, **[man crunch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/crunch.1.html)** and look for **`-d`** option

   ```
   -d numbersymbol
         Limits the number of duplicate characters.   -d  2@  limits  the
         lower  case  alphabet to output like aab and aac.  aaa would not
         be generated as that is 3 consecutive letters of a.  The  format
         is  number  then  symbol  where  number is the maximum number of
         consecutive characters and symbol  is  the  symbol  of  the  the
         character set you want to limit i.e. @,%^
   ```

You have written in your command, **`-d 1,`** that means No repetition of uppercase characters and **`-d 1%`** meaning No repetition of Numbers.

#### The Problem

- `-d 1,`

  You have specified to `-d` option that, there should be only one instance of characters and numbers ignoring any repetitions.
- `-t DD,,%%`

  But you have passed a pattern that itself contains repetition of letter `D`. As soon as `-d` option encounters `DD` in the pattern itself, It makes the program to exit out generating `0 lines`. Hope you understand now, what you were doing wrong.

#### The Solution / Workaround

Create 4-length wordlist and pipe it to `sed` or `awk` to append `DD` at beginning and finally redirect to `wordlist` file.

```
crunch 4 4 -d 1,% -t ,,%% | sed 's/^/DD/' > wordlist
```

OR

```
crunch 4 4 -d 1,% -t ,,%% | awk '{ print "DD"$1 }' > wordlist
```

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: Nice answer, probably the most important thing in your answer was the man page. Kudos